# ggplot2 geom_boxplot side by side with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have these data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(12),name=factor(rep(c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),2),levels=c("a","b","c")),side=factor(rep(1:2,6),levels=1:2),group=factor(c(rep("x",6),rep("y",6)),levels=c("x","y")),stringsAsFactors=F)
df$upper <- df$y+0.1*df$y
df$lower <- df$y-0.1*df$y
df$max <- df$y+0.25*df$y
df$min <- df$y-0.25*df$y
```

And I'd like to `ggplot`-`geom_boxplot` them such that there are two facets, on top are `df$group == x` and at the bottom are `df$group == y`, where in each facet `df$side == 1` appears to the left of `df$side == 2`. I also want to color `df$group == x` `darkgray` and `df$group == y` `darkred`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df,aes(name,color=group))+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=1)+scale_color_manual(values=c("darkgray","darkred"),labels=levels(df$group),name="group")+scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgray","darkred"),labels=levels(df$group),name="group")
p <- p+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group,lower=lower,upper=upper,middle=y,ymin=min,ymax=max),position=position_dodge(width=0),alpha=0.5,stat="identity")+theme(text=element_text(size=10))
p <- p+guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=FALSE),colour=guide_legend(reverse=FALSE))
```

`p` gives me:
[image]

which is close except for not having `df$side == 1` to the left of `df$side == 2`.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Seems like you're defining the wrong x-axis, does `ggplot(df,aes(side,color=group))` give you the correct output?

Comment: Can you elaborate what the expected output would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're after, it uses `interaction` to create a factor based on all combinations of the levels of its arguments (you could also use `side:name`):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, group=interaction(side, name),
               col=group, fill=group)) +
    facet_wrap(~group) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(lower = lower, upper = upper,
      middle = y, ymin = min, ymax = max),
      position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
      alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity")
```

[image]

It might be clearer to instead use colour  to show which side is which, as the facets already label the group:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, group=interaction(side, name),
               col=side, fill=side)) +
    facet_wrap(~group) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(lower = lower, upper = upper,
      middle = y, ymin = min, ymax = max),
      position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
      alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity")
```

[image]